# Phonegap Desktop App not reflecting project

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I created a Phonegap project and was testing that in browser with the help of the Phonegap app of desktop & mobile which runs the server to host our application. But all of a sudden my project isn't visible in the app any more and i can't even open that through the "Open an existing Phonegap project" option, it's not showing up ! what could possibly be wrong

Comment: Browse the www folder from a browser and look at the console for debugging any errors.

Comment: I tried running it in browser so the only error is that cordova.js not found ! which is not avaiable when we run it in the browser and phonegap developer app picks it from the platform we are running at, be it browser. Correct me if i m wrong ! @MACMAN